# Query returning too much data for Laravel collection?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

To avoid going to the db thousands of times for each user request to fetch their projects, I have refrained from using Eloquent relationships between the models that constitute a Project object. Originally, I had one vast SQL query to gather all needed data in one trip to the db, but am now breaking it down into two queries. But even this is apparently too much for the returned collection, which drops data silently (no error) after a certain point.

EDIT (added image): Screenshot of how "dropped data" appears to manifest in output from dd():

[3 dots where a toggle-triangle should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ecA.png)

A Project object consists of, e.g:

```
PROJECT
 ->assigned to a Group or Team (Team belongs to Group)
 -> has many Tasks
  -> Tasks can have many Notes
  -> Tasks assigned to many one or more Members of Group or Team, or to whole Team (within assigned Group)
   -> Members of Tasks are either Users or Teams 
 -> Project can have many Notes (... etc.)
```

Suffice it to say that the SQL needed to gather all the required data to compile a user's projects returns much data. Excerpt from original single query:

```
$rawProjects = Project::where('projects.owner', $userId)
    ->where('projects.completed', false)
    ->leftJoin('tasks AS Ta1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Ta1.project_id', '=', 'projects.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('memberships AS Me1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Me1.membershipable_id', '=', 'Ta1.id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('groups AS Gr1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Gr1.id', '=', 'projects.group_id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('groups AS Gr2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Gr2.id', '=', 'Ta1.taskable_id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('teams AS Te1', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Te1.id', '=', 'projects.team_id');
    })
    ->leftJoin('teams AS Te2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Te2.id', '=', 'Ta1.taskable_id');
    }) // [cut]
```

I've just begun to divide this process, to fetch Project and Task data separately (in two queries), then combine the fetched data downstream. Sadly, the collection returned by the task-getting query alone is too much. The collection drops data silently; I'm not getting any error. What surprises me is that, according to debugbar, the data delivered to the VueJs page totals a paltry 2MB.

(I'm now going to recode the Eloquent queries to raw SQL and bypass Laravel collections.)

**Question:** Is this expected behaviour from Laravel collections? (It seems like quite a severe limitation to me.)

**UPDATE**
Results from the raw SQL are the same, but it seems part of the problem is dd() itself, which seems to 'max out' at a certain point, confusing the issue somewhat. For example, print_r() returns all expected data. So the 3-dots-instead-of-toggle-triangle phenomenon is a red herring (see my comment in reply to apokryfos).

To expand on why I wrote "drops data" above: When I perform the query on a single project, the project is returned complete with all its data. When I fetch *all* the user's projects, data is missing from what is the 'bottom' – users assigned to the last project's task – of the array of Projects. This behaviour has nothing to do with dd() vs. print_r().

Comment: When you say "drops data" what do you mean? Are rows missing that you expect to see in the result? If so can you provide some sample data that would help reproduce the result?

Comment: By "drops data", I mean that data I know should be returned from a query is not present. This project is still in the test phase, so I am 'playing' all the users using the software. I was alerted to this phenomenon while testing assigning a task to three members of a particular team, but saw only 2 members returned in the page. Subsequent investigations via dd() led me to the issue/question I've raised here. After a certain point, output from dd() displays arrays that cannot be examined: there is no little triangle to toggle the array open, just three dots (...). I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: By the way, you should be using eloquent relationships rather than left joins. Yes you will do more queries but you will end up transferring a lot less duplicated data columns so overall it's more efficient

Comment: Is that true when the number of queries is potentially a factor of 100 lower, and likely even more than that, than with the left-join approach? I observed a radical speed increase switching to left joins, judging by the request-duration times displayed in debugbar. I've also read that performance issues bedevil sites that use Eloquent relationships where objects are complex, as in my case. The guy that hosts Laravel Daily on YouTube also expresses caution re. performance when using relationships; he has a whole video on it.

Comment: It depends on the size of each object but when you left join A, B, C, D, E then you get one row of A per joined relationship which can potentially result in getting the same row of A hundreds of times. If your database server latency is low then more queries which result the minimum data are better. Less queries would only be better if you have high latency between web server and database server or you have an unusually high bandwidth relative to latency. Of course this is without considering the complexity of instantiating the PHP class objects which depends on how complex you make them.

Comment: Thank you for that, aporkryfos, I shall revisit the matter and do more testing.

Answer (score 1):

My bad!

It was a bug in my code that was triggered by having the same user assigned to different tasks in 2 different projects, who then 'disappeared' from the query data when those 2 projects were captured by the query, only to 'reappear' when other combinations of projects were queried. Combined with the unexpected behaviour from dd(), I drew the wrong conclusion.

The fix was to reset/clear the array used to capture the users assigned to each task on each iteration of the relevant foreach() loop.

Comment: Try to use as much punctuation as possible when answering. e.g. `dd()` is better than writing it plainly and try "bolding" the core points. Without that the answer seems like a paragraph uninviting for the reader. Hoping that helps in future questions and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

For larger data sets use eager loading with eloquent relations and laravel Api resources, it's the best practice I think..  Here is reference [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) [Conditional Loading Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but that methodology – PostResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('posts')) – produces extraordinary numbers of calls to the db, even with e.g. <10 users or <4 projects. I departed from it intentionally; I can't see how eager loading solves this. Besides, I need to return all a user's active Project objects, and the entire object too. The nature of the software is such that the number of projects per user is unlikely to exceed 2, and besides, completed projects won't be returned. So chunks and eager loading currently look like dead ends to me.

Comment: can you provide db Query logs details?

Comment: Hi Faizan, thank you for offering to help solve this issue, but it was in fact a bug in my code, as you can see from the answer I just posted. No need for any further assistance!